# Ajax in WordPress - can't get variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Trying to transfer post ID from jQuery to PHP, without success ...

Can see the variable in the payload (webtools in Chrome), but can't get the variable in PHP,

If anyone can help - I would be very grateful :)

jQuery:

```
$("a.uc_more_btn.btn_reg").click(function(){
        var post_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                'action': 'get_the_ifarme',
                'pop_post_id' : post_id 
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Happy");
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
function get_the_ifarme() {
if(isset($_REQUEST['pop_post_id'])){
    $pop_post_id = $_REQUEST['pop_post_id'];
    $iframe_link = get_field("tour_register_link", $pop_post_id);
    echo '<iframe src="'.$iframe_link.'" height="820"></iframe>';
}
}
add_shortcode( 'tickets_iframe', 'get_the_ifarme');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_the_ifarme', 'get_the_ifarme' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_the_ifarme', 'get_the_ifarme' );
```

This function also needs to be a shortcode because the iframe will be placed in Elementor pop-up.

Comment: Can you also post the html element of `a.uc_more_btn.btn_reg` ?

Comment: <a class="uc_more_btn btn_reg" href="#book-popup" data-id="146">
<span>Rgister</span></a>

Comment: Can you check the ajax url is fine?

Comment: yes, working fine - gets status 200 - no errors

Answer (score 0):

Try access it using $_POST['pop_post_id'].

Comment: I tried, does not work

Comment: Pass admin-ajax url to the script, you can get the admin-ajax.php full url with admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ). i think your request url is incorrect.

Comment: The AJAX call gets status 200, runs perfectly and successfully. I can see the response, and the variable I need in devtools - but can't get the value from PHP. $_POST / $_REQUEST is empty.

Comment: @Haksuma Do you have any security plugin ? If you have, disable it temporary and check again.

Comment: no, no security plugin